# Understanding ManyToMany fields in Django with a through model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm having trouble understanding the use of ManyToMany models fields with a through model. I can easily achieve the same without the ManyToMany field. Considering the following from Django's docs:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

What I don't understand, is how is using the ManyToMany field better than simply dropping it and using the related manager. For instance, the two models will change to the following:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='members')
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're right, if you define the `membership` table explicitly then you don't need to use a `ManyToManyField`.

The only real advantage to having it is if you'd find the related manager convenient. That is, this:

```
group.members.all()  # Persons in the group
```

looks nicer than this:

```
Person.objects.filter(membership_set__group=group)  # Persons in the group
```

In practice, I think the main reason for having both is that often people start with a plain `ManyToManyField`; realize they need some additional data and add the table explicitly; and then continue to use the existing manager because it's convenient.

Comment: Excellent thanks. So it's down to preference which one I use?

Comment: @Johan: That's right, it just depends on what kinds of queries you want to run and how you'd like to express them in the language of the ORM. Personally I tend to add the `ManyToManyField` just in case it's ever convenient to use that manager.

Comment: In addition, m2m relationship with through guarantee the uniquity of relation. In the question example, nothing prevent to have 2 memberships with same person/group references

Comment: I have pressed -1 for this. I think this answer really needs improvements. Something in my answer bellow. But other thing: What is `membership`? From where is such name? If it should be an example of the m:n relation withouth `through=`, then we have only 2 models here: `group` and `person` :(

Comment: @mirek: Your criticism here, and your answer below, are based on a misunderstanding of the question. The OP isn't comparing using a explicit table or not. They're comparing using a m2m field or not in the presence of such a table. So to answer your question, `membership` exists in both versions. I've edited my answer slightly to make it clearer, but really you just need to re-read the question.

Comment: I actually ran into a use case.  A user can belong to multiple clients, but there are two kinds of profile information:
1) Settings that apply to all clients (put in Profile table)
2) Settings specific to client (Put in Profile2Client, a through table)

Comment: You also get the convenience of adding and removing members via very simple methods such as `group.members.add(Stan)` or `group.members.remove(John)` which manage the relationship for you.

Answer (score 28):

So I just wanted to add to anyone who is looking at this and may want another example to save them research. For one, I think it's important to note that in OP's questions, he should of removed the `Group` model not the `People` model and removed the matching field from the `Membership` model. That way, the model goes back to it's original meaning.

When looking at a many-to-many relationship, the `through` field can almost be contrived as the "why" to the many-to-many relationship. If we give the nomenclature a different name, it might change what the reader sees:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='RegistrationReceipt')


class RegistrationReceipt(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    paid_dues = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    fee_payment_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now, you can imagine yourself adding all sorts of logic whenever a member joins this club. When they joined? Why did they join? Did they pay? When is their payment date? etc. You can obviously tackle this relationship in different ways, but you can see more clearly the use of "through" in a Many-to-Many relationship.

Also, for those that know SQL. The **through** attribute/field is the way you customize the intermediary table, the one that Django creates itself, that one is what the **through** field is changing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not only for pointing out the mistake in OP's example but showing the real benefit for the explicit through table

Comment: There's no mistake in the OP's question. The `Person` model wasn't removed, they just wrote out the code for the models that would *"change"*. The result is a correct example of how you'd define an intermediary table if you didn't have a `ManyToManyField`. Your answer seems to be addressing why, when you have a `ManyToManyField`, you might want to use an explicit `through` model rather than the implicit one that Django makes for you. The OP's question is why should you use a `ManyToManyField` at all when you can accomplish the same thing without one.

Answer (score -3):

I have some problem with the answer from Kevin Christopher Henry.

I don't think that the equivalent of the `group.members.all()` without a `through="members"` is `Person.objects....`.

Instead I think it is `group.person_set.all()` if the M2M field is on `Person` side. Or `group.persons.all()` if the M2M field is inside `Group`.

But I think without `through=..` you have no control over the created table. It contains and will contain just 2 fields: both ID's of the related rows.

But with `through=..` you can create the model yourself and add (now or later) the additional fields, which often can have a good reason. Example of such field: `valid_from = DateField()`, or so.

Comment: Note that the last thing (about additional data ie. fields) is in the Kevin's answer too.