# One-To-Many and Individual in Django

Tags: python, django, relational-database

I've customized the django user object as follows,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    root = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I also have a feed and a Source object, which has a one-to-many relationship.

```
class Source(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Feed(Base):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    summary = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    shares = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

Now I want to simulate a bookmarking action and thus associate many feeds with one user. How do I do that in Django.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650362/understanding-manytomany-fields-in-django-with-a-through-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another model `Bookmark`.

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fed = models.ForeignKey(Feed, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_read_page = models.IntegerField()
```

Then add this field to your `Feed` model.

```
reader = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Bookmark')
```

Comment: This looks excellent. Two quick questions, though, how can I access all bookmarks for an user, second, what does last_read_page actually do?

Comment: sorry for the late response.. you can access the bookmarks of a user by `<user_object>.bookmark_set.all()`. and `last_page_read` is the last page the user read that feed. like a bookmark for a book.