# Why is django ManyToManyField asymmetric?

Tags: django, django-models

A classic example of a `ManyToManyField` ([django 4.2 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) or [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650362/understanding-manytomany-fields-in-django-with-a-through-model)) looks something like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Why the asymmetry?  We have this natural scheme where a `Person` can belong to `Group`s through a `Membership` and vice versa.  So why does `Person` make no reference to this?  Or, perhaps better phrased, why does the framework see fit to encourage us to state the relationship only on one side?

```
# No one writes this:
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, through='Membership')
```

Comment: Depends on the query that your app needs most. 

You can write a M2M field for `groups` in the `Person` model. (Like what you have written at the end of your question). There is no issue with it.